# How can I find beer or wine shops online in India?

Tags: wine, specialty-beers, online

I am a passionate traveller, and this is all I ever wanted. But the only problem I face in the new place is finding the beer shop. Is there any way of finding one without any hassle? My journey is always incomplete without beer.

Comment: Eh, a search engine?

Comment: Perhaps try travel on SE.  I appreciate that you are new (we all were once), maybe ask a question about Indian beers, everyone here loves new questions and stories, but we do have to keep to the rules of the site.  Oh and one more thing, Welcome to our little corner!

Answer (score 3):

Yes, finding a nearby beer shop or nearby wine shop is hassle free now all because of [Nearbytheka.com](https://nearbytheka.com/).

NearbyTheka is India’s first online portal where you can locate the list of nearby beer shops, pubs, bars, wine shops, cafes, and thekas close to your location just within a click. All you need just to search your existing location through GPS and explore the nearby beer shops, just like that.

The motto of NearbyTheka is to provide a hassle-free way out to search nearby wine shops. Along with that, they believe to provide a platform for all daaru lovers to spice up their life with the list of nearby thekas, yummiest nearby chakna, nearby cafes, pubs, bars and daaru party theme merchandise with the latest daarubaaz trends at amazing prices.

Answer (score 2):

**How can I find beer or wine shops online in India?**

First of all, try using a search engine and employ the Punjabi language or some other popular Indian language. Many languages are employed locally or are used in very particular regions of India.

Here are [3 Websites to Order Alcohol Online in India](http://durofy.com/3-websites-to-order-alcohol-online-in-india/):

> You can order alcohol online in India with these websites.
>
> Let’s take a quick look at the laws in India to order alcohol before we share the list with you.
>
> In India, the retail industry has bloomed a lot in the last ten years, from selling clothes to eyewear, anything and everything can be bought online. But, there is one question that troubles a lot of people especially the youngsters, Can you purchase your drinks online?
>
> The short answer is YES, you can buy and sell alcohol online. But, in order to sell it online, you need to seek permissions from the state government and ensure that your business model complies with the state laws. You also require permissions to buy/sell liquor in public places. Every state has different age restrictions regarding hard drinks, hence selling or buying drinks depends on the age restrictions.
>
> Prohibition is incorporated in the Constitution of India among the directive principles of state policy which means that legislative powers of alcohol consumption are under the power of respective states. Recently, Bihar had prohibited the sale and consumption of country liquor in April 2016. The Liquor online business model is a risky model but it can be done if you comply with state laws you can run a successful business.
>
> Here are few online alcohol vendors, who are running a successful online Alcohol portal:
>
> [Madhuloka](http://madhulokagroup.com/) is probably one of the most famous outlets for ordering alcohol online. Based in Bangalore, Madhuloka has a wide range of drinks including premium brands as well. The vision of Madhuloka is to provide their guests with best and widest range of wine and spirits. They operate only in Bangalore.
>
> Madhuloka Wine Boutique is about wines to drink – not just wines that impress at tastings. We particularly emphasize drinkability and try to offer wines, which do not just impress on first taste but leave you wanting another glass.
>
> [Whiskey Marketplace](http://www.whiskymarketplace.com/) (India)
>
> Probably the best place to buy whiskey online, the website is 100% secure and safe for buying rum, cognac, vodka, gin, and Armagnac. The feature that makes the website unique are the filters, age and price filters which allow the users to buy aged whiskey. The website also contains filters for the retailers you want the drinks from and the age of the whiskey you wish to purchase.
>
> For people who wish to know about the latest trends and events, detailed analysis of the liquor industry they can browse through the [Spiritz Magazine](http://spiritz.in/). The website also informs the users about the latest fashionable drinks available in the market.
>
> Go on, shop your drinks online!!!